# SMT packages library in eagle

Tags: eaglecad, library

I can't find eagle library with "empty" smd/smt packages.

I found THT packages in ic-packages.lbr.

Where I can find SSOP, TQFP and other smd packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the generic packages I have used with Eagle are in my "package" library, which should be (I think) included in the Eagle Tools release at http://www.embedinc.com/pic/dload.htm.

However, if you need a package, the safest and usually simplest option is to just make it yourself.  What's the big deal?  By the time you typed a question here and get a answer, you would be done if you spent the time making it yourself.

### Added in response to comment

No, there are many more than 2 packages in my Eagle package library.  I just looked, and there are only 2 *devices* in there, TQFP64 and TQFP80.  I forget why I made those, but there must have been some special purpose at the time.  In any case, you asked about *packages*, not devices, so I don't see why you care about these two devices.

The point to creating your own, and the reason I always do it, is that it would take more time to vet and possibly modify someone else's package than to simply create my own.  Or put another way, defining is easier than detailed checking.  Also, others aren't going to create packages with my conventions for the tPlace, tValue, tName, and tDocu layers and other details.

Spending 5 minutes making a package is better than spending 10 minutes checking someone else's package, finding things that I need to change, and then making the changes.

Comment: I need many packages, I want to make some SMD-THT adapters. I see no point of creating own packages if there are already professionally designed packages.

Comment: There are only 2 packages there - TQFP-64 and TQFP-80.

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete.

Comment: @Passe: This should be a comment to the question then, not to a answer. If you feel that way, then voting to close the question and possibly downvoting the question if you think it was poorly asked (although I don't think this one was) makes sense. I fail to see the logic in downvoting a answer though, unless you have a specific disagreement with the answer itself.  In that case it would be useful to point out what you disagree with in the answer.

Comment: The comment should have been on the question. But adding an answer to a off topic question encourages bad behavior. And adding a answer that recommends a specific product is also off-topic.

Comment: @Passe: This question isn't really off topic.  It is something faced by a lot of Eagle users, and its reasonable enough to ask if there is a library of common packages out there somewhere.  As for the product recommendation, that doesn't apply.  First, if a product really does answer the question, then it's OK to mention it, although you should point out any affiliation you have to it.  However, in this case I didn't mention any of my products, and if you'd bothered to follow the link I gave before jumping to conclusions you'd have seen it points to a page of *free* downloads.